# How can I convert an array to a hash that reflects the number of times each unique element in the array appears in the array?

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

Given an array I would like to create a hash whose keys are the unique elements of the array and whose values are the numbers of times the corresponding key appears in the array.

For example, if the array were

```
["americans", "oath", "oath", "generation", "americans"]
```

the associated hash would be

```
{ "americans"=>2, "oath"=>2, "generation"=>1 }
```

Comment: `group_by` and `transform_values` using `&:count`.

Comment: Please include a clear explanation of the problem. it's completely unclear how your output should be produced by your input.

Comment: My edit can be regarded as a "Hail Mary". Incidentally, that term derives from a woman's rugby game played in 1976 when, in the dying seconds a player--Mary Southby--was thrown with the ball over the goal line by her teammates to win the game. The term has subsequently been used to describe the last play in a game of American football in which the team behind throws a desperation pass to the end zone, one which rarely succeeds.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sorry, but the term “Hail Mary” in sports [predates your 1976 rugby claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass). It was popularized by American football quarterback Roger Staubach in 1975, but apparently goes back roughly 50 years prior to that with the Notre Dame University football team. One article I found says it originated in 1922, but Wikipedia did a hand-wavy “goes back at least to the 1930s”.

Comment: @pjs, I've never cared for fact-checkers... I see, however, that where I wrote "1976" I meant to write "1916".

Answer (score 3):

There is the [`Enumerable#tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) method that does exactly that:

```
["americans", "oath", "oath", "generation", "americans"].tally
#=> { "americans" => 2, "oath" => 2, "generation" => 1 }
```

Comment: Or if you like working harder, for fun: `["americans", "oath", "oath", "generation", "americans", "crisis", "crisis", "generation"].each_with_object(Hash.new{0}) { |x, hsh| hsh[x] += 1 }`

Comment: @Chris, not just working harder but also wishing to support Ruby versions preceding 2.7, `tally`'s birthplace.